# How to interpret OLS regression with two dummy variables

Tags: regression, stata

I am currently working with a regression model that includes two dummy variable (y = divorce 0 = no, 1 = yes | x = households 0 = two-parent, 1 = one-parent) and I am really struggling with the interpretation of the results.
Could anyone tell me what the constant and slope exactly mean?
Thank you so much!

Here is my regression table:[image]

Comment: They mean you observed 252 divorced two-parent households, 35 non-divorced two-parent households,  805 divorced one-parent households, 70 non-divorced one-parent households, and you should be analyzing these data with a chi-squared test or a log-linear analysis of this $2\times 2$ table instead of applying linear regression.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how you get those numbers?

Comment: There are many ways.  I used the fact that these counts $(a,b,c,d)$ are determined by the number of observations $n,$ the two coefficient estimates $\beta_i,$ and the residual sum of squares $SSR.$  Each of these four statistics establishes one linear relation among the four counts and all four relations are independent, giving (generically) a unique solution, $$\pmatrix{a\\b\\c\\d}=\pmatrix{1&1&1&1\\\beta_0-1&0&\beta_0&0\\0&\beta_0+\beta_1-1&0&\beta_0+\beta_1\\(1-\beta_0)^2&(1-\beta_0-\beta_1)^2&\beta_0^2&(\beta_0+\beta_1)^4}^{-1}\pmatrix{n\\0\\0\\SSR}.$$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your outcome is binary and you are using OLS, you are in essence running a [Linear Probability Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_probability_model). Since your predictor is also binary, OLS is estimating two conditional probabilites here:

$P(\text{Divorce}=1|\text{OneParent}=0) = \beta_0  = 0.238$

$P(\text{Divorce}=1|\text{OneParent}=1) = \beta_0 + \beta_1  = 0.238 + 0.095 = 0.333$

Your $t$-statistic is further telling you that there is a statistically significant difference between the divorce rates of the two groups (e.g., at $\alpha = 0.05$).

Note two things:

- There are more standard test procedures for a simple comparison of proportions, e.g. $\chi^2$ tests or Fisher's exact test which you can employ outside a generalized linear model framework (test results and confidence intervals should not differ meaningfully given the large sample size here)
- A good reason to specify a model nonenethelss would be to include further predictors, e.g. some of which could be confounders of your relationship between predictor and outcome. If you want to answer a causal question with your model, you will definitely have to adjust for some potentially ommitted variables, or look for instrumental variables (there is a huge literature on instrumental variable approaches to estimate trans-generational effects in economics and epidemiology). $R^2 < 1\%$ tells you that the vast majority of variation in your data is unexplaiend
- There is some debate around linear probability models. In general, most people recommend link functions that limit the range of outcomes between 0 and 1, as in logistic regression. This will become relevant when you add continous predictor variables (e.g., age) which would extrapolate probabilities of divorce beyond 0 and 1

Comment: Isn’t $\beta_0 = 0.24$?

Comment: absolutely, edited it. Not used to Stata output